# Como solucionar el error "Segmentation faul(core dumped)"

Tags: bucles

Ya se que han solucionado este error anteriormente pero con las respuestas no logro solucionarlo, por favor ayuda, soy nueva programando.
El error aparece en el segundo ciclo for donde hago uso del vector notas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int notas[3];
    for(int k=0;k<=3;k++){
        if(k!=3){
            cout<<"Inserte nota"<<k<<":"<<endl;
            cin>>notas[k];
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Inserte nota del examen final:"<<endl;
            cin>>notas[k];

        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No nos basta únicamente con el síntoma, necesitamos todo el código para averiguar cuál es el origen del problema. Es muy probable que sea debido a la definición de `notas` o a su reserva de memoria. Imagino que sería del tipo `int notas [4];`, ¿no?

Comment: He editado la preguntando agregando el codigo completo

Comment: En mi primer comentario te di la solución. Prueba a usar `int notas[4];` para usar índices del `0` al `3`. Tal y como lo tienes tú definido sólo puedes usar 3 valores, del `0` al `2`.

Comment: Cómo debería definirlo para que del 0 al 3 pueda usar 4 valores ?

Comment: Por tercera vez: `int notas[4];`

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás sufriendo es que necesitas alojar suficiente espacio en la matriz `notas` para albergar 4 valores, del `0` al `3`.

En tu código defines la variable `notas` de la siguiente manera:

```
int notas[3];
```

Eso reserva 3 índices en `notas`, del `0` al `2`, por lo que cuando deseas escribir el índice `3` en la siguiente línea, da el error de **detectada pila machacada** (*stack smashing detected*):

```
cin>>notas[k];
```

Que te indica que estás "machacando" un valor de la pila que no deberías mediante esa instrucción.

La solución es alojar suficiente espacio para ese cuarto índice (el número `3`) de la siguiente forma:

```
int notas[4];
```

El código completo corregido sería el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int notas[4];
  for (int k = 0; k <= 3; k++) {
    if (k != 3) {
      std::cout << "Inserte nota " << k << ":" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> notas[k];
    } else {
      std::cout << "Inserte nota del examen final:" << std::endl;
      std::cin >> notas[k];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

O bien el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int notas[4];
  for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    std::cout << "Inserte nota " << k << ":" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> notas[k];
  }
  std::cout << "Inserte nota del examen final:" << std::endl;
  std::cin >> notas[3];
  return 0;
}
```